# `ValueError: no active connection` using aiosqlite

Tags: python, aiosqlite

im pretty sure i have everything written correctly here! yet i keep getting an error,
`ValueError: no active connection`
the error points to `in inventory cursor = await con.cursor()`
this is my full code

```
import aiosqlite

async def db ():
     async with aiosqlite.connect('inventory.db') as con:
         return con

async def inventory():
        con = await db()
        cursor = await con.cursor()
        await cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE inventory (user, dupes, name, char, rarity, image1, thumbnail1, image2, thumbnail2, UNIQUE (user, name, char))")
        await con.commit()
        await con.close()
        await cursor.close()
```

ive tried reordering the commit/close every way i can think of, im just really not sure? any help is appreciated! also fair warning- im essentially a complete noob w coding as of right now

Comment: This is not your full code.  This code defines some functions but they are never called.  Presumably you have some main-level code somewhere else that you did not show.

Comment: ah well yeah, theres more code in other files (they're all hooked up properly with one and other) i figured only this file was needed for troubleshooting, but ill paste the other if needbe! its code for a discord.py bot, and these fuctions are called when i start it up, thats when the error is put